# In WPF Stretch a control to fill a ListView Column

Tags: .net, wpf, listview

How do I make a control fill the whole cell in a ListView (with a GridView)? I've played around with various properties, but the control is always it's minimum size.

Here's my xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewUserControlTest.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewUserControlTest"
  Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserControlCell">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" />              
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>        
        <ListView Name="MyListView">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="30" Header="Col1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Col2" CellTemplate="{StaticResource UserControlCell}"  />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**Edit** Sorry I changed the question because I had eliminated the user control as the source of the problem. It happens with any control.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

After narrowing down my question I was about to Google and find an [answer here](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/30/fill-wpf-listview-columns).

Basically for some reason the ListViewItems are set to align to the Left. Setting them to Stretch fixes this problem. This is done through a style like so:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This unfortunately affects every column, but then you can set the contents of other columns to left, right, center as explained in the link.

Comment: Extend the style definition like this `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">` . . . . . Without this `BasedOn` all default settings of the style are gone.

Answer (score 6):

Another almost-solution is to do something as follows in your datatemplate that goes into the gridviewcolumn

```
Width="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor , AncestorType=ListViewItem, AncestorLevel=1},Path=ActualWidth}">
```

This results in it stretching the textbox to the width of the column, but the right edge is clipped and not rendered. I haven't fixed that part yet. So the already accepted answer is still probably the best one.

Here's a sample DataTemplate which does this.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EditableStringElement}"
          x:Key="cellSalutation">
<TextBox Text="{Binding _RecipientData._Salutation.Value , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding _RecipientData._Salutation.IsEnabled}"
         Width="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor , AncestorType=ListViewItem, AncestorLevel=1},Path=ActualWidth}">
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Use this one, Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type VirtualizingStackPanel}}}" , It is working perfectly with scroll...

Answer (score 3):

Your user control specifies the values for the "Height" and "Width" properties. Nothing is allowed to override properties you have explicitly set. Remove "Height" and "Width" and the control's container will be able to mess with the size.

You might want to set a reasonable "MinHeight" and "MinWidth" to prevent containers from squishing you.

Different containers do different things to your control's size; for example, Grid expands you to fill the grid cell you're in, while StackPanel shrinks you to your minimum size. So you might need to deal with that too.

Comment: Bingo - if you want stuff to rezize really well, don't ever supply explcit widths and heights to anything! (except min/max) :)

Comment: I remove the height and width in the constructor for non-design time as seen above. I tried as you suggested and removing it altogether, but there's no change. It just is sized as the MinHeight and MinWidth

Comment: Sorry about making your answer not match the question, I played around a bit more and it wasn't the user control that was the problem.