# WPF - HorizontalAlignement on WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I know how to Align Textbox, but in the case of a WrapPanel, with several Textboxes inside, I couldn't manage to find a way to Align the whole text on center, also tried to make a TextBlock, with inside TextBlocks, but no way :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Priorite}" Width="70">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrioriteMin}"/>
          <TextBlock Text=" - " />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrioriteMax}"/>
        </TextBlock>
      </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when the `FrameworkElement` which displays your cell content is created it copies the alignment properties from the corresponding `ListViewItem`. Which leads to `HorizontalAlignment.Left`.

Here you can read more about what each value does: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/alignment-margins-and-padding-overview

So to achieve what you want you have to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` on your `ListViewItem`.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

See also [In WPF Stretch a control to fill a ListView Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493345/in-wpf-stretch-a-control-to-fill-a-listview-column)

Comment: I don't unerstand something yet : With your modify I expected that all columns would be stretched, so all columns would be aligned on center. But no, only my column is aligned on center(that's what I want it's cool, just don't understand well how it works)

Comment: Just understood I think, my ItemContainer is aligned on the left, and the TextBlock is Align on center (of ItemContainer), as ItemContainer is smaller than column, on the end it is on the left. What you do is set the container's width at column's width so all my alignments are taken in account, right?

Comment: @Siegfried.V I did some more research to find out what really happens, therefore I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for these details, just one question,can you explain why people downvote the question? Is there something wrong with it? I admit that I don't always understand how votes are done here, as I noticed I lost some reputation when answers are downvoted.

Answer (score -2):

You can use styles to target the TextBlocks within a WrapPanel:

```
<WrapPanel>
     <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
     </WrapPanel.Resources>
     <TextBlock>MyText</TextBlock>
     <TextBlock>MyText2</TextBlock>
<WrapPanel>
```

I think the above should work in your case, though I may have misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: Tried it, but no result, all is still aligned on the left

Answer (score -3):

The example you gave seems to center align horizontally just fine!

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

does the trick, and you don't even need

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
```

for your textBlock

Comment: well in fact, it is not aligned, that's why I added TextAlignment, then tried to put TextBlocks in a TextBlock

Comment: Do you need to specify the width of the GridViewColumn?
If you try without it, it should get aligned...

Comment: Thanks for proposal, I tried but nothing changed, it is aligned on the left always